# cannot find symbol class AutocompletePrediction

Tags: android

I upgraded my version of gms from 8.4.0 to 9.6.0. I break a lot of things after Sync Now. Is AutocompletePrediction has been removed in 9.6.0 version?

Before upgrade:

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:8.4.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:8.4.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:8.4.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:8.4.0'
```

After upgrade:

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:9.6.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:9.6.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:9.6.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:9.6.0'
```

Stacktrace:

```
Error:(15, 46) error: cannot find symbol class AutocompleteFilter
Error:(16, 46) error: cannot find symbol class AutocompletePrediction
Error:(17, 46) error: cannot find symbol class AutocompletePredictionBuffer
Error:(18, 46) error: cannot find symbol class Places
Error:(48, 13) error: cannot find symbol class AutocompleteFilter
Error:(51, 83) error: cannot find symbol class AutocompleteFilter
Error:(110, 23) error: cannot find symbol class AutocompletePrediction
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:compileClientReleaseJavaWithJavac'.
Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.
```

Answer (score 7):

Besides adding play-services-location library you need also add play-services-places library as Places and Autocomplete classes has been moved to that library, in my case i use

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-places:9.6.1'
```